# How can I help a user subscribe to an external calendar to Google calendar on an android device?

Tags: android, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

Currently, my app has the ability to help a user add a single event to their Google calendar:

```java
final Intent calendarIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        .setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event")
        .putExtra("beginTime", startTime)
        .putExtra("endTime", startTime + 7200000L) // 2 hours
        .putExtra("title", name)
        .putExtra("description", description.toString())
        .putExtra("eventLocation", address);

// later
startActivity(calendarIntent);
```

However, many users want to automatically add all their events to their Google calendar. Our server team made an ICS feed which people can [subscribe to as an external Google calendar](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37100). But this involves copying and pasting URLs and is kind of confusing for end-users.

On the web, we can link people to a URL of the form `http://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=OUR_ICS_URL`, and they will be able to relatively easily add the feed from there. However, when you visit this URL on the Android browser, you get all kinds of weird popups about mobile vs. desktop websites, and even the advanced android users on our development team couldn't figure out how to get the calendar added from there.

Another thing I looked into was the Google Calendar API, but it appears that their [calendar list insert method](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert) needs a google calendar ID, not a URL to an external calendar.

So, is there any good solution here? It seems like there ought to be a way to help our users subscribe to their calendars without requiring them to go to their desktops and open up a full-sized web browser. But nothing I've tried has yielded any results.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use [AuthSub](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/authsub.html) to authenticate your users, then you would be able to use the calendar list insert method. I think the [Zend framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.calendar.html) does it this way.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the calendar list insert method can only accept Google calendar IDs, not arbitrary external calendar URLs. Am I missing something?

Comment: I guess you're right, I just thought for an instant that there would be a way to reproduce the Zend framework getCalendarListFeed() functionality, since they state in their documentation: "The calendar service supports retrieving a list of calendars for the authenticated user. This is the same list of calendars which are displayed in the Google Calendar UI, except those marked as 'hidden' are also available." But I'm no Zend expert, so analysing this is a bit beyond me.

Comment: Yeah, I just checked the code behind that function (in the Zend_Gdata_Calendar namespace) and it looks like they are manually pulling the calendar web page (in background) from the external URL and extracting the information from its DOM. Not an elegant solution for a simple Android app, that's for sure.